# GCC Warning: "Initialization from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]"

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, gcc, warnings

'''
`bool loadArray(unsigned int array[8][8]) { int* p = array; ... }`
'''

I have a function that loads array[8][8] with user input. Everything works fine, but trying to compile it with gcc (c99) it gives me a warning (pointing at 'int* p = array;') that says: 'initialization from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]'.

What exactly am I doing wrong in the code?

Comment: As an argument, the definition `unsigned int array[8][8]` is really the same as `unsigned int (*array)[8]`. And the type `int (*)[8]` is not compatible with the type `int *` (the type of `p`). Just as the compiler tells you. What are you really trying to do? What is the purpose of `p`?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I want to create a pointer that points to the beginning of the array so that I can fill it.

Comment: Why can't you use `array[i][j]`? Why do you need the pointer? How do you "fill" the "array"? Please try to create a [mcve] to show us.

Comment: And for future questions, please take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). And learn how to [edit] your questions.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I could do that, but I thought a "sleeker" solution would be to transform the 2D array to a 1D array and fill it in one for loop 'for (int i = 0; i < 64; i++) { fill *(p + i) }'

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude will do that, thank you - I am new to stackoverflow as well as programming

Comment: Don't try to be "clever"... The compiler will in 99.99999% of all cases be much smarter than you when it comes to being "clever" and creating optimized code. :) Instead concentrate on writing good, simple and understandable code (which incidentally also makes it more maintainable).

Comment: @JohnPace Whilst accessing a 2D array linearly is a common trick that ought to work (on most systems), it is not actually valid according to the C standard.

Answer (score 0):

The warning is pretty self-explanatory. You cannot point at a `unsigned int array[8][8]` with a `int*`. It's invalid C so you get a compiler message.

You could do it if it was a one-dimensional array, because when used in most expressions or as a function parameter, such an array "decays" into a pointer to the first element.

But in case of an array of arrays, a pointer to the first element of `unsigned int [8][8]` becomes an "array pointer" `unsigned int (*)[8]`. Probably not what you wanted.

Instead, you could iterate through every dimension of the array of arrays:

```
for(size_t i=0; i<8; i++)
{
  int* p = array[i];
}
```

Or if you just wish to populate the array then:

```
for(size_t i=0; i<8; i++)
{
  for(size_t j=0; j<8; j++)
  {
    array[i][j] = something;
  }
}
```